# How to display a popup message after a delay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display a popup message when the user visits my site and next popup after 3 hours. 
 I am half way done, as I have implemented the popup message displaying for the first visit. 
Please guide me how can I display a popup after delaying it for 3 hours?

Thanks.

Comment: Share some of your code, It will help people answer your question. use jquery setInterval, it will probably be what you need.

Comment: As @Billy said, Show us what you have do so far.

Comment: @Billy  I kind of disagree.  setInterval is not a jQuery function, and you can't use it alone in this instance because the user will likely navigate from page to page during that time.  You need either cookies or localstorage too.

Comment: Yeah , you're right, I should have put and & in there, As far as I know Jquery doesn't have a similar function to setInterval and normal js is used. I could and probably am wrong ( again )....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using javascript you can use local storage by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = localStorage['visited'];
    if (!visited) {
        localStorage['visited'] = Math.round(+new Date()/1000)
        //Run initial pop up code
    }


   window.setInterval(function(){
        visited = localStorage['visited'];
        if(visited != "finished") {
            if (visited + (3600*3) < Math.round(+new Date()/1000)) {
                //Run popup code for after 3 hours
                localStorage['visited'] = "finished";
            }
        }
   }, 60000);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have already suggested, setInterval is probably what you are looking for. see this jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dswknovp/   good luck!

HTML:

```
<span id="alertText"></span>
```

JS:

```
var myTimer = 1000*3; // every 3 seconds for testing, use: 1000*60*60*3; //for 3 hours

var myStart = setInterval(function(){
    myAlarm()
}, myTimer);

function myAlarm() {
    document.getElementById("alertText").innerHTML += "-Time elapsed-";
    //you can change this to, for example: alert("Time is up");
}
```